# Generalised ideal gas in d dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I'm working through Mehran Kardar's book and I can't get the question on calculating the particle flux of an ideal gas in d dimensions, and help would be great.

Show that the number of particles hitting area A in a time dt arriving from a specific direction Ω⃗ , with a speed v, is proportional to A · vdt cos θ · nf (v)dv , where θ is the angle between the direction Ω⃗ and the normal to the wall, and f(v) is the probability density of being at velocity v.

Then summing over all directions Ω⃗ with the same polar angle θ, demonstrate that

$$dN(θ,v) = A · vdtcosθ · nf(v)dv · S_{d−1} sin^{d−2} \theta \ d\theta $$,